# Git pull provide user and pass in the command

Tags: git

I want to automate some **git** commands, including a **pull**, but I don't want neither to configure and store the user credentials nor to be prompted for them, but **to provide them along with the command**. This way the script would run in new machines with no special configuration, clean and smooth.

Is this possible in Git?

Comment: Sure, you can [generate some SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) and add them to your authorized keys files of the git server.

Comment: I was thinking about something like: git pull origin --username=user --pass=thepass ... I know the SSH keys setup but I wanted to avoid that, since it's... well... not clean. It requires setup. I want my script to run successfully wherever I run it, just providing the necessary parameters.

Comment: agree with @sjagr, that way you reduce security issues when handling user+pass in many machines. You will have to run ssh-add <certificate> on every machine, writting the pass only that time.

Comment: I want that the user that runs the scripts uses his / her own credentials, not a previously generated SSH key. If possible.

Comment: Let the user decide how they want to provide their credentials. If this is intended for use by multiple users, you can't embed any one person's password in the script, and any other approach requires each user to specify their personal credentials any way. Just let the script prompt for the information if a private key is not provided.

Comment: No, that's not what I want. I want users provide their credentials along with the rest of the parameters when they run the script. I don't want any setup in the machines. Prompting is forcing the user to be in front of the screen during the process, so it's not a solution. Example: scp command allow specifying user and password in the command. This is cool because let's you automatize scp commands with any other configuration on the machine. That's what I want in Git. It should provide some way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the credentials as argument to the command is a terrible thing to do. When you run

```
some-command --password=secret
```

anyone able to run `ps u` on your machine can see the password while the command is executed.

You can write a simple [credential helper](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) that would provide username and password on request.

If you insist on providing credentials on the command-line, you can actually embed username and password on the URL, like

```
git clone http://user:password@example.com/path/to/repo.git
```

Comment: It doesn't work for git hosted in visualstudio.com, at least... :(